# Find nth number that does not belong to a set of numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, programming

So, this problem is a competitive programming problem, but I find it to be quite mathematical. Basically, we have to find the nth number that does not lie in a set of number. The set of numbers given are: {1, 2, 4, 6} + all numbers of the form 10+4*k (k >= 0). So the set is: {1, 2, 4, 6, 10,14, 18...}. I feel the answer will be done using binary search but I am not sure how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: But we could just say, that all powers of $3$ are not in the set? What is "the" $n$-th number that does not lie in this set? Why not $3^n$?

Comment: Why do $1,2,4,6$ lie in this set?

Comment: How do you binary search an infinite set?

Comment: Also, the definition of the set is simple enough that you can just write down an explicit formula for the $n$th element inside its complement. No need for any fancy programming or searches.

Comment: Hint : List the positive integers NOT in the list , a clear pattern emerges. It should be not too difficult to find a closed form (by cases) for the $n$ th element in this complement list.

Comment: Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of all nonnegative integers. Then, $\{1,2,4,6\} \cup (10+4\mathbb{N})=\{1,4\} \cup (2+4\mathbb{N})$. So, one could just as well replace $\{1,2,4,6\}$ and $10+4k$ with $\{1,4\}$ and $2+4k$ respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\left\{\left\lfloor\frac43n\right\rfloor-1\right\}=\{0,1,\;3,4,5,\;7,8,9,\;11,12,13,\;15,16,17,\;\ldots\}$$

If you toss out a few numbers at/near the beginning of this sequence, you have the complement of the given sequence. I'll leave the details of adjusting this to you.